# Gravação em ficheiro .txt (Linguagem C)

Tags: c

```
    void gravar_para_ficheiro(struct estrutura2 *lista , struct estrutura *filme)
{
FILE *fp;
int i , index;
fp = fopen(listafilmes, "w+");
if (fp != NULL) {
    fprintf(fp,"Filmes %s\n\n",lista->nomes);
    for (i=0; i<lista->num_filmes; i++) {
        index = lista->filmes[i];
        fprintf(fp,"Nome do cinema : %s",filme[index].cinemas );
        fprintf(fp,"Filme: %s", filme[index].filme);
        fprintf(fp,"Genero: %d\n", filme[index].genero);
        fprintf(fp,"Duracao: %d\n", filme[index].duracao);
        fprintf(fp,"Idade Minima: %d\n", filme[index].idade_minima);
        printf("\n");
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
    }
```

Olá, gostava de saber se no meu código consta algum erro que impede a gravação de dados no ficheiro txt. Neste momento, quando chega á parte de gravar o programa dá erro.
Obrigado

EDIT : [Código completo, main.c](https://drive.google.com/open?id=15Du69gGNOmKQ32-maPOpO-eilBZMBKwp)

Só dei upload no ficheiro de codigo, por isso pode dar-vos erro por causa do ficheiro txt em que está definido para gravar.

Comment: Qual erro é exibido?

Comment: O programa simplesmente fecha, parece o erro a dizer que o programa parou de funcionar, e vai abaixo.

Comment: Poderia postar o código completo?

Comment: onde está a declaração do ```listafilmes```?

Comment: Não me parece que a instrução `index = lista->filmes[i];` seja o que pretende, mas aconselho a colocar a definição das estruturas para ser facil de se ver

Comment: O codigo completo é um bocadinho grande, cerca de 600 linhas, vou colocar o ficheiro para voces puderem utilizar e conseguirem ver melhor a situação

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Baseado no seu raciocínio, segue um código (testado) capaz de gravar em um arquivo texto chamado `lista_filmes.txt` o conteúdo de uma `lista` de `filmes`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct filme_s
{
    char cinema[100];
    char titulo[100];
    int genero;
    int duracao;
    int idade_minima;
} filme_t;


typedef struct lista_filmes_s
{
    int num_filmes;
    filme_t * filmes;
} lista_filmes_t;


int gravar_para_ficheiro( const char * ficheiro, lista_filmes_t * lista )
{
    FILE  * fp = NULL;
    int i = 0;

    fp = fopen( ficheiro, "w+" );

    if(!fp)
        return -1;

    for( i = 0; i < lista->num_filmes; i++ )
    {
        fprintf( fp, "FILME #%d\n\n", i + 1 );
        fprintf( fp, "\tNome do cinema: %s\n",lista->filmes[i].cinema );
        fprintf( fp, "\tTitulo: %s\n", lista->filmes[i].titulo );
        fprintf( fp, "\tGenero: %d\n", lista->filmes[i].genero );
        fprintf( fp, "\tDuracao: %d\n", lista->filmes[i].duracao );
        fprintf( fp, "\tIdade Minima: %d\n", lista->filmes[i].idade_minima );
        fprintf( fp, "\n");
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}


int main( void )
{
    lista_filmes_t lst; /* Lista de filmes */

    /* Aloca memoria na lista para acomodar 3 filmes */
    lst.filmes = malloc( sizeof(filme_t) * 3 );
    lst.num_filmes = 3;

    /* Cadastro Filme #1 */
    strcpy( lst.filmes[0].cinema, "Cinesystem");
    strcpy( lst.filmes[0].titulo, "Back to the Future");
    lst.filmes[0].genero = 5;
    lst.filmes[0].duracao = 116;
    lst.filmes[0].idade_minima = 0;

    /* Cadastro Filme #2 */
    strcpy( lst.filmes[1].cinema, "Kinoplex");
    strcpy( lst.filmes[1].titulo, "2001: A Space Odyssey");
    lst.filmes[1].genero = 5;
    lst.filmes[1].duracao = 142;
    lst.filmes[1].idade_minima = 12;

    /* Cadastro Filme #3 */
    strcpy( lst.filmes[2].cinema, "Kinoplex");
    strcpy( lst.filmes[2].titulo, "Contact");
    lst.filmes[2].genero = 5;
    lst.filmes[2].duracao = 149;
    lst.filmes[2].idade_minima = 8;

    /* Grava lista de filmes no arquivo */
    int ret = gravar_para_ficheiro( "lista_filmes.txt", &lst );

    /* Verifica se houve erro */
    if( ret < 0 )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Fatal: Erro de criacao/gravacao de arquivo!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    /* Libera memoria ocupada pela lista de filmes */
    free( lst.filmes );

    /* Sucesso */
    return 0;
}
```

Conteúdo do arquivo gravado:

```
FILME #1

    Nome do cinema: Cinesystem
    Titulo: Back to the Future
    Genero: 5
    Duracao: 116
    Idade Minima: 0

FILME #2

    Nome do cinema: Kinoplex
    Titulo: 2001: A Space Odyssey
    Genero: 5
    Duracao: 142
    Idade Minima: 12

FILME #3

    Nome do cinema: Kinoplex
    Titulo: Contact
    Genero: 5
    Duracao: 149
    Idade Minima: 8
```